# Looking for a word matching my definition

Tags: meaning

Is there a word to describe when someone say something just to appease you or end the conversation but they do not truly mean what they say they just want to end the discussion? I thought the word could maybe me patronizing or facetious but that’s not it.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)